# "network DISABLED" on new installation on Dell Inspiron 15 3000 Series laptop

Tags: networking, dell

After a new installation of Ubuntu, WiFi is not working...
I'm posting the following because I saw someone asking for them in another post, but I have no clue what they mean... :)

```
> sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 01
       serial: 38:b1:db:c5:54:b9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.4.0-26-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7d00000-f7d7ffff memory:f7d80000-f7d8ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: 74:e6:e2:0b:ed:04
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.0.21 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c00000-f7c00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff


> lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:020c]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1028:0651]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

> rfkill unblock 0

> rfkill list
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Thanks,

-Ed

Comment: Wi-Fi is locked by a hardware button or switch? Did you try to use it?

Comment: I don't have a button for that, but [Fn]+[PrtScr] seems to be the WiFi on/off -  tried already but doesn't change - actually it doesn't seem to make any difference, doesn't go from enable to disable nor vice-versa.

Comment: OK, then run `sudo modprobe -r dell_rbtn && sudo rfkill unblock all`.

Comment: done...
sudo rfkill list
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Does Wi-Fi work?

Comment: It's working !!! :-)

Comment: Hold on. We need to make it permanent.

Comment: Thank you @Pilot6 VERY MUCH!

Comment: Not done yet, I am writing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wi-Fi is blocked by `dell_rbtn`. You need to blacklist it.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rbtn.conf <<< "blacklist dell_rbtn"
sudo modprobe -r dell_rbtn && sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Wi-Fi should work.

Comment: Thank you Pilot6. I did it and reboot the machine and WiFi is back working.